# Magento get qty foreach product

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, cart

I have a small problem with product QTY, i have an ajax update cart extension and i need to display product qty, everything is ok until I add two products in cart. For example if I add first product in cart the quantity is perfect, but when I add the second product the quantity for all product is the last product quantity. I have the following code:

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($cart_items as $items) {
            $qtyr = $items->getQty();
    }

           $htmlItem .=' <div class="qty-btngroup">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" title="Qty" size="4" value="'.$qtyr.'" name="" readonly="readonly">              
                        </div>

        $_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
                ->setCartitem($html)
```

How can I solve this, I need the qty to be display for each product ..

**Update:** I paste here my entire public function: http://codepad.org/2ovDqy4i

Comment: second (})  should closed at end d code

Comment: Hi amit thank you for your answer, but if I close { at the end, the products is duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move that bracket out and place it after `$htmlItem`. Like this..

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach($cart_items as $items) {
    $qtyr = $items->getQty();

    Mage::log($items->getSku()); // EXAMINE THIS

    $htmlItem .= ' <div class="qty-btngroup">'
        . '<input type="text" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" title="Qty" size="4" value="'.$qtyr.'" name="" readonly="readonly">'
        . ' </div>';
}  // THIS GOES HERE
$_response = Mage::getModel('ajaxminicart/response')
    ->setCartitem($html);
```

Comment: Hi thank you but is not working, the second product and the quantity input field is replicating.

Comment: look here i paste my entire public function here: http://codepad.org/2ovDqy4i

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a misplaced bracket.  Just make sure your each iteration of the `foreach` loop covers all of that `$htmlItem`.

Comment: look at the code here http://codepad.org/2ovDqy4i I add the code with your modifications but there instead 2 products I have 4 :)

Comment: You see 4 products instead of 2 because you're looping through the quote items TWICE. SEe lines 32 and 129.

Comment: yes you are right and how must look the code to work? i am a begginer, can you modify that code from http://codepad.org/2ovDqy4i to me? you can paste it in the same website

Comment: but if your look at the line 32 there is item not items, items exist only in the second foreach

Comment: I add my foreach in front of line 32 and is the same thing the second product duplicate all product for 2 times